# How to get a total from JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to get a total of each column form a JSON data. below is my JSON data I want to get a Total of each column.

```
[
 {"campaign":"MD001","seen":650,"taken":62,"eligible":542,"total":1000,"ind":"E"},
 {"campaign":"MD002","seen":550,"taken":52,"eligible":342,"total":1000,"ind":"E"},
 {"campaign":"MD003","seen":800,"taken":69,"eligible":642,"total":1000,"ind":"W"},
 {"campaign":"MD004","seen":500,"taken":62,"eligible":527,"total":1000,"ind":"E"},
 {"campaign":"MD005","seen":350,"taken":29,"eligible":992,"total":1000,"ind":"w"},
 {"campaign":"MD006","seen":550,"taken":52,"eligible":342,"total":1000,"ind":"W"}
]
```

Means above their is an "eligible" & every "eligible" has a different value, so I need to get a total of "eligible" from above data.

Comment: And what prevents you from looping ? What did you try ?

Comment: There're several steps involved: parse JSON, loop an array, calculate a sum. Do you really need help on all of them? What have you tried?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: let me explain.. I just want a total of every "eligible" element of array.. need to print on the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you have to calculate it:

```
var data = // your json data
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    total += parseInt(data[i].eligible);        
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CVpxR/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
data = [
    {"campaign":"MD001","seen":650,"taken":62,"eligible":542,"total":1000,"ind":"E"},
    {"campaign":"MD002","seen":550,"taken":52,"eligible":342,"total":1000,"ind":"E"},
    {"campaign":"MD003","seen":800,"taken":69,"eligible":642,"total":1000,"ind":"W"},
    {"campaign":"MD004","seen":500,"taken":62,"eligible":527,"total":1000,"ind":"E"},
    {"campaign":"MD005","seen":350,"taken":29,"eligible":992,"total":1000,"ind":"w"},
    {"campaign":"MD006","seen":550,"taken":52,"eligible":342,"total":1000,"ind":"W"}
]

var total = 0;

$.each(data, function(index, item){
    total = total + item.eligible;
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2A9qv/2/

Comment: Please don't call json a variable which doesn't contain some JSON.

Comment: Woops, changed it! :$